# I have never repaired my "car/cars" like that -and I only have one car at a time - the same meaning?

Tags: meaning, plural-forms, singular

‎"I have had three cars in my life. I have never had my **car/cars** repaired that way."

Also assume I only had one car at a time.

Do both of them mean the same?